# Using TabContainer OnDemand feature to lazy load UserControl, when to perform work?

Tags: asp.net, tabs, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit, mvp

I'm trying out the OnDemand feature of the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit TabContainer to delay execution of expensive operations until the tab is loaded.

On my page there are a few tabs, and each tab's content consists of a single user control

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" ActiveTabIndex="0" OnDemand="True" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" HeaderText="tab 1" runat="server" >
        <ContentTemplate>
            <UC:Tab1 runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" HeaderText="tab 2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <UC:Tab2 runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
</ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

Each of these user controls is then wired up to a presenter with a custom MVP framework I inherited.  The presenter is executed in OnLoad

```
// In user control
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    presenter.BuildView();  // this is what I want to delay until the tab is active
}
```

Since OnLoad is always called, regardless of the tab being active, I know it's the appropriate event to attach to.  What is the proper event to attach to, so that I can achieve the same effect as the [example provided here](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2011/11/16/ajax-control-toolkit-november-2011-release.aspx) with the SqlDataSource's selecting event only firing when the tab is loaded.

Maybe override Render?  Or CreateChildControls?